# SSH Tunnel or Reverse Tunnel

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, unix, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to establish a SSH tunnel to allow VNC/ARD connections (ports 5900 and 3389).
However I'm uncertain about a certain thing:

Let's say **machine A** has IP 192.168.103.1 and has services running on ports 5900 and 3389.

I want to SSH to the **server** that has IP 192.168.103.254.

**Machine B** 192.168.103.2 wants to connect to machine A by using an tunnel on the **server** 192.168.103.254 and different ports (let's say 6001 and 4001)

So, the setup will look like this:

**Machine B** 192.168.103.2 --> **VNC to Server** 192.168.103.254:6001  (Server redirect --> 192.168.103.1:5900)

I know a little bit about SSH tunnel and reverse SSH tunneling but I'm unsure which command I need.

Please note:

- The Client PC has to connect to the server (the other way around is not possible since the clients have different IP addresses everytime)

Things I tried:

```
ssh -f user@server.hostname.net -L 6001:localhost:5900 -N
```

This command succeeds but when I try to connect to it I get a connection refused error:

```
Tims-Macbook-Pro:~ Tim$ telnet server.hostname.net 6001
Trying 192.168.103.254...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.103.254: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I also tried this

```
sudo ssh -NT -R 6001:localhost:5900 user@server.hostname.net
```

The command also gives a connection refused error when I'm trying to access it.

```
Tims-Macbook-Pro:~ Tim$ telnet server.hostname.net 6001
Trying 192.168.103.254...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.103.254: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: What have you tried? Anything? Give us the commands you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened. As it is, you're asking for us to spoon-feed you a solution, which would be very un-professional of us to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should reach Machine A's port 5900 when connecting to the **server's** localhost port 6001 with this command:

```
ssh -L 6001:192.168.103.1:5900 root@192.168.103.254
```

Check this resource for a deeper understanding of SSH tunneling: http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html

UPDATE:

If you need multiple clients accessing Machine A's port 5900 via the **server** like this:

```
Client1
Client2 ---> port 6001 ---> 192.168.103.254 ---> port 5900 --> 192.168.103.1
Client3
```

You need to run this command (In the **client**):

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:6001:192.168.103.1:5900 root@192.168.103.254
```

All clients connecting to the **server** port 6001 will reach Machine A's port 5900 with that command.

Comment: This works for the server itself but other clients can't use `telnet 192.168.103.254 6001` because the connection gets refused: `telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.254 Connection refused`

Comment: At first I thought this worked but I had to enter the commands on the server, which I can't like I said in my first post `The Client PC has to connect to the server (the other way around is not possible since the clients have different IP addresses everytime)`

Comment: You mean, you need to be able to open the ssh tunnel from the client?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Of course I could write a script that executes the above SSH command on the server but isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hmm.. I've never tried this, buy it may work, from the client, run: ssh user@server 'ssh -L 0.0.0.0:6001:192.168.103.1:5900 root@192.168.103.254'. That is going to run an ssh command via ssh. Replace user@server according to your needs.

Comment: Getting `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` and `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).`

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect to your "gateway" server but we don't know if that kind of traffic is allowed. Your best bet is to try mapping the remote port to a local port, as you did in the first example, but you need to actually point to the server you want to connect to, like this:

```
ssh -f user@server.hostname.net -L 6001:192.168.103.1:5900 -N
```

If not, how would ssh know which IP needs to forward the connection to? By doing this you are mapping port 5900 of the remote server 192.168.103.1 to a LOCAL (your machine) port (6001 in this case) through a SSH tunnel via server.hostname.net.

Now, to connect you just access a local port:

```
telnet localhost 6001
```

Comment: I executed `ssh -f osxserver@192.168.103.254 -L 6001:192.168.103.1:5900 -N` on my client (machine A) and then tried the following command on machine B `telnet 192.168.103.254 6001` however I'm still getting `telnet: connect to address 192.168.103.254: Connection refused`

Comment: You are mapping a port from a remote machine to a local port in your own machine. That's why you should do the telnet to localhost: `telnet localhost 6001`.